# Tomcat 7.0 won't show Web Application in browser Windos

Tags: eclipse, spring, tomcat

I am building an application that uses Spring+MyBatis+JSP in Eclipse. Its a very basic application. The program complies without any errors or warnings. When I click on **Run on a Server** in the project I get the following output in the console.

**Output**:

```
Jul 17, 2013 4:42:45 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin/client;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/lib/i386;C:\Python33\;C:\Oracle\Ora92\bin;C:\Program Files\Oracle\jre\1.3.1\bin;C:\Program Files\Oracle\jre\1.1.8\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files\Symantec\Workspace Virtualization\;C:\Program Files\Enterprise Vault\EVClient\;C:\Program Files\Lenovo\Access Connections\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14;C:\Program Files\Perforce;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\8.0\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\;C:\Program Files\Nmap;C:\eclipse-jee-juno-SR2-win32\eclipse;;.
Jul 17, 2013 4:42:45 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:MyBatisHelloWorld' did not find a matching property.
Jul 17, 2013 4:42:46 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jul 17, 2013 4:42:46 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jul 17, 2013 4:42:46 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1133 ms
Jul 17, 2013 4:42:46 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jul 17, 2013 4:42:46 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.12
Jul 17, 2013 4:42:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Set web app root system property: 'webapp.root' = [C:\Users\Anand_Roongta\workspace1\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\MyBatisHelloWorld\]
Jul 17, 2013 4:42:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing log4j from [C:\Users\Anand_Roongta\workspace1\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\MyBatisHelloWorld\WEB-INF\classes\log4j-helloworld.xml]
Jul 17, 2013 4:42:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'HelloWorldMyBatis'
2013-07-17 16:42:48,436 INFO  DispatcherServlet:454 FrameworkServlet 'HelloWorldMyBatis': initialization started 
2013-07-17 16:42:48,502 INFO  XmlWebApplicationContext:510 Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'HelloWorldMyBatis-servlet': startup date [Wed Jul 17 16:42:48 IST 2013]; root of context hierarchy 
2013-07-17 16:42:48,597 INFO  XmlBeanDefinitionReader:315 Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/HelloWorldMyBatis-servlet.xml] 
2013-07-17 16:42:49,090 INFO  DefaultListableBeanFactory:596 Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@ac0f75: defining beans [helloWorldController,numbersServiceImpl,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,viewResolver,dataSource,txManager,sqlSessionFactory,sqlSession,userDao,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor]; root of factory hierarchy 
2013-07-17 16:42:49,844 INFO  DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping:315 Mapped URL path [/index] onto handler 'helloWorldController' 
2013-07-17 16:42:49,844 INFO  DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping:315 Mapped URL path [/index.*] onto handler 'helloWorldController' 
2013-07-17 16:42:49,844 INFO  DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping:315 Mapped URL path [/index/] onto handler 'helloWorldController' 
2013-07-17 16:42:49,844 INFO  DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping:315 Mapped URL path [/helloWorld] onto handler 'helloWorldController' 
2013-07-17 16:42:49,845 INFO  DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping:315 Mapped URL path [/helloWorld.*] onto handler 'helloWorldController' 
2013-07-17 16:42:49,845 INFO  DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping:315 Mapped URL path [/helloWorld/] onto handler 'helloWorldController' 
2013-07-17 16:42:50,184 INFO  DispatcherServlet:473 FrameworkServlet 'HelloWorldMyBatis': initialization completed in 1745 ms 
Jul 17, 2013 4:42:50 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jul 17, 2013 4:42:50 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jul 17, 2013 4:42:50 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 3847 ms
```

This according me is a working application. But the application simply won't show up in a browser window. Tomcat doesn't open any browser (like it does as its default behavior like an internal browser or Firefox etc.) Any suggestions.?

Comment: Do you mean the problem is that the browser is not launched when you start Tomcat? Is it working when you enter your URL in the browser?

Comment: Open a browser by yourself and go to http://localhost:8080/MyBatisHelloWorld

Comment: Nope. I tried entering the URL that Dirk mentioned. Its giving me a 404. I fail to understand that without any errors how am I supposed to find out why the 404 is occurring.

Comment: @user2339071 Do you have anything set to respond to `.../MyBatisHelloWorld/`? If not, try pointing to a resource that you actually expect to exist (e.g. `.../MyBatisHelloWorld/foo.html`).

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz : I have set my <welcome-file> as index.jsp and I have a jsp named index.jsp in the Web-Content directory. I guess that should be displayed right..? I have also added a "@RequestMapping" to (\index) in my Controller.

Comment: Resolved the issue. Restarted Eclipse and re-installed Tomcat 7. Works perfectly.